# Calling a stored procedure from C# code returns -1

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure. When I run it from Management Studio, everything looks OK, but when I call it from C#, it returns -1. Any ideas?

This is my stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.GetImageData 
    @TableName NVARCHAR(50), 
    @ImageID BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT [File] FROM ' + QUOTENAME (@TableName) + 
               ' WHERE Id =' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @ImageID)

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

And I am calling it like:

```cs
var test = DataConnection.context.GetImageData("TestTable", (long) 1);
```

Comment: what result are you expecting? since you're doing a `select`, the *data* is in the grid results, but it isn't clear that you're *consuming* any grids

Comment: There are a few reasons for error 1) Do not have credentials to execute procedure 2) The default Database is wrong.  Add default Database in connection string or add "Use Database_Name'  3) The parameters types to not match.  Add parameter to c# query.  4) A long is not the same as a BIGINT.

Comment: Thank you, I executed a different proc and it is working fine- so I have the credentials. I switch long to Int64 and I have the same error. How can I test your third pointer. I am using the proc with Entity. When I execute this script in management studio: Exec GetImageData 'Test' , 2 is working fine

Comment: Can you add the mapping code of the stored process on the context?